# There is some way to stream a photo with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, socket.io

I'm creating a webchat and i want to give to the user the option of select an image from it's file system and share it to the other members of the chat room by streaming.

There is some way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a browser? This has nothing to do with streaming.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to upload a file in HTML? How to serve a file over HTTP?

Comment: I want to transmit the file directly between the user file system and the other users of the chat, without having to upload the file

Answer (score 2):

well streaming the photo to server and then to connected clients of a room, it won't be such an overhead for the server, since it uses streams, which can be handled in different ways, compress, resume, pause, etc.

`Socket.io` might not be the >>best<< solution in transmitting binary data, but you can always base64 encode the image and use the string for all purposes.

of course the `correct` solution will come in the near future with WebRTC and projects such as 
[PeerJS](http://badassjs.com/post/43090030238/peerjs-a-peer-to-peer-networking-library-in-javascript).

hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs)

```
// Incoming stream from browsers
  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){

    // broadcast to all other clients
    for(var id in bs.clients){
      if(bs.clients.hasOwnProperty(id)){
        var otherClient = bs.clients[id];
        if(otherClient != client){
          var send = otherClient.createStream(meta); // create writable stream
          stream.pipe(send); //pipe data to otherClient
        }
      }
    }
  });
```